# DirectMemoryAccess and Exception

Tags: java

If I directly access memory using `ByteBuffer(etc)`, what kind of exception it can throw if the memory used too large(off heap)? Does JVM has any control over it? I understand that JVM in this case has got nothing to do. Please correct me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the Oracle JVM, if you attempt to call `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` with an argument that is larger than available memory you'll get an `IOException` with the message "Direct buffer memory". You can also get this exception if you don't set `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` to the amount of memory that you need.

In addition, you can get an `IllegalArgumentException` as indicated by the documentation.

Once you've allocated the buffer, if you try to read past the end of the buffer you'll get a `BufferUnderflowException`; if you try to write past the end of the buffer, you'll get `BufferOverflowException`. These are also in the documentation.

Comment: you are are not going to pass any arguemets to JVM. everything is being controlled dynamically here. In that case, can I expect the same exception as you mentioned above?

Comment: @UVM - if you don't have enough memory to allocate, you're going to get an `OutOfMemoryError`. It doesn't matter why you don't have enough memory.

Comment: My comment about the `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` is that the Oracle JVM uses it to control the total available memory for direct buffers (at least on the 64-bit JVM). I don't know what its default value is, but I have banged against that value in the past. So you might end up getting an exception even though you think you have plenty of memory available. If you're running on a 32-bit JVM, it probably isn't necessary.